# Recursive Function not returning from base condition

Tags: java

I am trying to return a direction, either up,down,left or right from base condition and in the recursive condition I am looking for a possible location where I can move. But the program only returns 'q' which is initialized when function starts. I know it has something to do with the unwinding of stack but I don't know exactly how to solve this problem.
Here is the Maze:

```
char [][]Maze = {{'S','#','#','#','#','#'}, 
                 {'.','.','.','.','.','#'},
                 {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                 {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                 {'.','.','.','#','.','G'},
                 {'#','#','.','.','.','#'}};
```

Here is the code:

```
public static char BackTrace(char[][]Maze, int x, int y)
{
    char direction = 'q';
    if (Maze[x+1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'd';
    }
    else if (Maze[x-1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'u';
    }
    else if (Maze[x][y+1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'r';
    }
    else if (Maze[x][y-1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'l';
    }
    else
    {
        Maze[x][y] = '+';
        if(Maze[x+1][y] == 'X')         /// Start moving Down
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);
        }
        else if(Maze[x-1][y] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Up
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x-1, y);
        }
        else if(Maze[x][y+1] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Right
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y+1);
        }
        else if(Maze[x][y-1] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Left
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y-1);
        }

    }
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: x+1 means that row is incremented which means moving down the array.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably need to check and make sure you aren't going out of bound. Instead of lines like

```
if (Maze[x+1][y] == '.')
```

you'll want to check your in range with

```
if (x+1<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '.')
```

otherwise your program should be crashing, depending on where you start.

Second, you have no `'X'`s in your maze so all of recursive cases are not going to get executed. I assume they should be `'#'`s, so

```
if(Maze[x+1][y] == 'X')
```

which never works (in addition to a possible error), should be something like

```
if(x+1<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '#')
```

in order to involve the `'#'`s. These may not make a difference depending on how soon you hit a `'.'`, which in your maze appears to be immediately.

Third, you are never changing the value of direction, so recursive step is going to fail. The line

```
BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);
```

might return from a base case with `'d'` and then that `'d'` goes nowhere. I assume you want to get the direction from your base case in which case you should try

```
direction = BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);
```

and similarly modify the other 3 recursive calls. This should get keep you from getting `'q'` unless there are no `'.'`s or `'#'`s around.

I don't know if those changes will make your method do what you want, but they will get it doing something more than returning `'q'`.

Final result:

```
 public static char BackTrace(char[][]Maze, int x, int y)
 {
    char direction = 'q';
    if (x+1<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'd';
    }
    else if (x-1>=0 && Maze[x-1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'u';
    }
    else if (y+1<Maze[x].length && Maze[x][y+1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'r';
    }
    else if (y-1>=0 && Maze[x][y-1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'l';
    }
    else
    {
        Maze[x][y] = '+';
        if(x+1<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '#')         /// Start moving Down
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);
        }
        else if(x-1>=0 && Maze[x-1][y] == '#')    /// Start Moving Up
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x-1, y);
        }
        else if(y+1<Maze[x].length && Maze[x][y+1] == '#')    /// Start Moving Right
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y+1);
        }
        else if(y-1>=0 && Maze[x][y-1] == '#')    /// Start Moving Left
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y-1);
        }

    }
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: `if (x<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '.')` ==> `if (x+1<Maze.length && Maze[x+1][y] == '.')`

Comment: I have changed the code. But it still returns direction variable with 'q' set into it. Debugger shows that the direction variable is set to 'd' but when stack unwinds and last return statement is called direction variable returns 'q' again.

Comment: public static char BackTrace(char[][]Maze, int x, int y) 
This function is just a part of the program when while finding the path the program moves in the wrong direction and hits a wall. Then it has to backtrace. The reason there are no X's is because they are put when code runs and a path is being traced.

Comment: Is that `'+'` meant to be an `'X'`?

Comment: No. Its just used as a marker to see whether its backtracking or not.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure you're logic is correct since I can't see what the rest of code is doing. If you want to add it all I may change my answer. Possibly you are getting boxed in between `'#'` which I assume are walls and some other character, maybe `'+'` when you backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I got it. Thanks to all. The problem was that every time stack was unwinding the old value of direction kept on changing the new value. Just had to add a return statement after each function call so that when stack unwinds the new value is returned. Here is the code:

```
public static char BackTrace(char[][]Maze, int x, int y)
{
    char direction = 'q';
    if (Maze[x+1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'd';
    }
    else if (Maze[x-1][y] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'u';
    }
    else if (Maze[x][y+1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'r';
    }
    else if (Maze[x][y-1] == '.')
    {
        direction = 'l';
    }
    else
    {
        Maze[x][y] = '+';
        if(Maze[x+1][y] == 'X')         /// Start moving Down
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);
            return direction;
        }
        else if(Maze[x-1][y] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Up
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x-1, y);
            return direction;
        }
        else if(Maze[x][y+1] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Right
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y+1);
            return direction;
        }
        else if(Maze[x][y-1] == 'X')    /// Start Moving Left
        {
            direction = BackTrace(Maze, x, y-1);
            return direction;
        }

    }
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this code solves your problem. Assuming the initial call is calling `BackTrace(Maze, 0, 0)` the code will enter the first `if` and set `direction = 'd'` and then will `return direction`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to assign the return value from the recursive calls to BackTrace to your variable direction.
(i.e. `direction = BackTrace(Maze, x+1, y);` etc.)

Comment: It still returns with the 'q'.

Comment: Did you change all lines? Do all calls to the function return q or only, for example, the last one in your program?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to look for the problem using debugger. It shows that direction variable is set to 'd' when the base condition is true. But when stack unwinds and control is transferred to BackTrace function and the last return statement is called the direction variable is again set to 'q'.